# Simplifying (P AND Q) OR (NOT P AND NOT Q)

Tags: logic

Can that expression be more simplified or is it already in it's simplest form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what logical connectives you can use. If you have only *and*, *or* and *not* at your disposal, then no, it cannot be further simplified.

Notice that it means "P if and only if Q" -- that is, it's true exactly when P and Q have the same truth value. Symbolically,
$$ (P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)
$$
is equivalent to
$$ P \iff Q
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$ (P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies P)
$$

Comment: Ok thanks! I have a Maths test tomorrow and wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything! Again, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @ Grantwalzer Yes I know. I wanted to spell it out.

Comment: Then I can maybe contribute Alt+0150 and Alt+0151.

Comment: @Grantwalzer But it was worth saying. (I added to the answer). Thanks.